# Remove parameters using .htaceess

Tags: .htaccess

i am using swf file as audio player. i am pass file/parameter using this link
when user open link SWF file open in new window which URL is

```
http://songs.example.com/files/audio_player.swf?audio_file=URLOFMP3FILE&color=FFFFFF
```

i want just display

```
http://songs.example.com/files/audio_player.swf
```

Hide all parameters from user using .htacess

Comment: If URL displays `http://songs.mnilay.com/files/audio_player.swf` how you audio player know which file to play?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove those, they are gone. You just may cloak that by an iframe and do a redirect.
Another way would be using POST instead of GET.